# How to write data in .plist?

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsdictionary

I'm trying to save some comments in a plist, that's OK cause its just a prototype. The problem is that i can read from plist but when I try to write and read after that, it throws an "array out of bounds" exception. I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Comments" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


NSMutableDictionary *newComment = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newComment setValue:commentTitle.text forKey:@"title"];
[newComment setValue:comment forKey:@"comment"];


[plistArray addObject:newComment];
[plistArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
```

That works fine, then i try to read:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Comments" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *) [plistArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]);
```

And it throws the exception.

If I add the item manually to the plist, it works fine, i guess it means that my reading code its fine.

Could it be the structure of my plist?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <array>
 </array>
 </plist>
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

I added the "description" to the array before writing to the plist. If i use the following code:

```
NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
//    NSString *aFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Comments.plist", aDocumentsDirectory];
//
//    NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aFilePath];
```

The return is (null)

But if i use:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Comments" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

i can see the contents of the array, and its all working properly.

The problem is: In both ways i cant write to the file, it keeps returning "NO". And i already checked the permissions

Comment: Post the stacktrace when the exception occurs.

Comment: That's not a stacktrace.  A stacktrace lets to see *where* you were in your code when it crashed.

Comment: Already figure it out. The writting code is not working, i just dont know why

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to write the file into ***mainBundle***. Definitely not possible. 
You will have to write the plist file to **Documents** or **Application Support** folder of the app.

***Create File Path in Documents Directory :***

```
NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *aFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Comments.plist", aDocumentsDirectory];
```

***Write to FilePath***

```
[plistArray writeToFile:aFilePath atomically:YES];
```

***Read From FilePath***

```
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aFilePath];
```

Comment: We're close. I changed the code, but i still can't write in the file, its return NO. Whats the problem??

Comment: you are saving 2 values in the Dictionary. One is `commentTitle.text` , which I assume is NSString. What is `comment` ?

Comment: A quick re-iteration. You are starting off with a Plist file saved in the MainBundle. Do you really need it. When u start the app, does it have some value which you would like to use. If not, ditch the Comments.plist of the mainBundle and start off with a fresh NSMutableArray.

Comment: commentTitle its the title, comment its the comment itself. Both are strings

Comment: Ok. Did you check if the `plistArray` is valid before Writing to File. Can you put an NSLog before the `WriteToFile` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

1. (May or may not be a problem). If the file does not exist initially, the `initWithContentsOfFile:` selector will return nil, causing the rest of your code to be no-ops.
2. (Probably the cause). You may *not* write to the bundle resources directory. Store your file in the Documents or Caches directory instead.

To locate your documents directory, use something like this:

```
- (NSString*) pathForDocument:(NSString*)documentName {
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if(documentDirectories.count < 1) return nil;
    return [[documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
}
```

Comment: 1 its not the cause, i can read from the file if i insert the item manually.

Comment: i didn`t get the second way. I use this code to get the path for the documents directory, then i use [plistArray writeToFile: ] for that directory?

Comment: You write to a file, not a directory. For example `[plistArray writeToFile:[self pathForDocument:@"someFile.plist"] atomically:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you writing a file into your bundle?

Then, to address your problem, check if you actually did write the file.

```
if ([plistArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO])
    NSLog (@"Written");
else
    NSLog (@"Not Written");
```

Also, log your array when you're read it using `-(void)description` to check the contents of the dictionary.

**Edit**

As you said that you're not writing to your plist.  For now, just create a test plist on your desktop.

```
NSString *testPath = [[NSString stringWithString:@"~/Desktop/Comments.plist"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
if ([plistArray writeToFile:testPath atomically:NO])
    NSLog (@"Written");
else
    NSLog (@"Not Written");
```

If that still returns Not Written, then there's something wrong with your dictionary.  Which I doubt because it's just strings (Though they could be placeholders for asking your question on stackoverflow.  The docs states that the classes in the dictionary must be of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary).  If that says written though, I'm guessing it doesn't write to your bundle because of permissions, which then you have to change your plist location to somewhere else other than your bundle, which I **highly** recommend.

Comment: Ok we are on the right path now. The return is "Not Written" But why?

Comment: Call `description` on the array before you write it.  What's inside?

Answer (score -2):

If you only put one item in the array, you should obviously use index 0 instead of 1 when reading from it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *) [plistArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: It's not that. I just changed the "0" for the "1" cause i added one item manually to check if the reading code was working fine